# Laravel 5.7 validation makes nothing

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-validation

My function works by itself but the validation is not executed. Does anyone know what I forgot to add?

This is a snippet of my code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Player;
use App\Tournament;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $data=$request->all();
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name' => 'alpha|min:2|max:30',
        ]);
        
        
        
        if(Auth::check()){

            $foo = Foo::create([
                'first_name' => $request->input('fist_name'),
                'last_name' => $request->input('last_name'),
            ]);
 
            if($foo){
                return redirect()->route('foo.show', ['foo'=> $foo->id])
                ->with('success' , 'Foo created!');
            }
 
        }
         
        return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Error when creating the foo');
    }
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: dd($request); after validation pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try different approach like:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

...
$data=$request->all();
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name' => 'alpha|min:2|max:30',,  
        ]);
```

Comment: thx you! I changed my code, but I have know a problem with the last part og the function.  ```if($data){
                return redirect()->route('players.show', ['player'=> $data->id])
                ->with('success' , 'Spieler erstellt');
            } ```

Comment: i cant understan you but the missing part of my code is about to check validation and u can do that by:     if($validator->fails()){
                    return ERRORS
                }
                return ok

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the validation now works but last part of my code ```if($data){
                return redirect()->route('players.show', ['player'=> $data->id])
                ->with('success' , 'player created');
            }```

will display an error message: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: your current error has nothing to do with the question. It's better to post as new one or ask in chat.

Comment: keep $foo as return... check by dd(); what is the content of $data, that is not your object update in the code above

Comment: $data was my "$foo" before

Comment: you not save an object with create then7

Comment: @JahStation I checked my code again and the validation doesn't works any more.

Comment: you are on a loop, clen up your code, make variables name more clear, and if create not works try save(). dd() show that nothing is being saved. usere request just to fish data and then use others var for validate, storing etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'category' => 'required',
        ]);

        //validating input

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->with('toast_error', $validator->messages()->all()[0])->withInput();
        }
// more code to run when if statement is executed with true for validated data
    }
```